# java awt text input do not editable in LFS linux

Tags: java, linux, awt, linux-from-scratch

After done a LFS(linuxfromscratch) system, I has 2 problems with input, some applications like google docs (presentations edit in browsers) and some java apps apparently do not recognize the keyboard input, the first one was resolved adding UTF-8 locale, but the java no way.
So I do some research and limited it in a awt scope. It means all apps writed in java awt do not recognize the keyboard inputs.
I tried http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/awt.html , but no success to solve the issue.
I too recompiled the libXt after the new locale.

I don't have Qt, awt is qt dependent?

Using eclipse(which is java app and do not have the issue), I created a little app using awt to reproduce the problem. The problem is here but it's don't give a stack trace nor a message warning.

From this moment I haven't idea how to solve or track this issue.

Some help/tip?

Here a simple program to reproduce the problem (jdk1.7.0_21)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.TextArea;   

public class testmain extends java.applet.Applet{
       public void init()
       {
          Panel p;  
          setLayout(new BorderLayout());    
          p = new Panel();
          TextArea x = new TextArea();
          x.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
          x.setText("asdf");
          x.setEditable(true);
          p.add(x); 
          add("Center", p); 
          p = new Panel();  
          p.add(new Button("One"));
          p.add(new Button("Two")); 
          Choice c = new Choice();  
          c.addItem("one");
          c.addItem("two");
          c.addItem("three");   
          p.add(c); 
          add("South", p);
       }

       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
          Frame f = new Frame("Example 4"); 
          testmain ex = new testmain(); 
          ex.init();    
          f.add("Center", ex);  
          f.pack();
          f.show();
       }
}
```

Comment: whats happends when you use Swing JApplet, JFrame, JPanel, JTextArea and JComboBox instead of prehistoric AWT Components

Comment: I tried the http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jtextarea-class-example sample, and received the same results. The fist time I got this problem was in oracle websphere instalator, that some text inputs do work other don't

Comment: what about oracle awt / swing developers? there is a official place to question it ?

Comment: I'm meaning Linux OS ....

Comment: I'm a LFS user and java programmer, no way to leave linux because a java/awt/swing dependency or problem, it's easier to leave java =p ... It may be a awt dependency... I said awt developers, because they can have ways to identify which dependency is it. But I don't know where to find they;

Comment: one correction... the fist time I got this problem was in oracle WEBLOGIC not websphere(ibm)